# Using AND condition with the same column having different values

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to fetch the "FormResponseQuestions" where both the conditions are satisfied.

For example :-

```sql
Select * from "FormResponseQuestions" as FQ where (
          FQ."qId" = 'a04c848c-9cf5-4de5-8d2b-b10d12a16501' 
          AND (
            FQ."oIds" @> ARRAY[ '1385b9cd-662d-43e0-8dbb-1bbc3977c7bb' ] :: UUID[]
          )
      ) AND (
          FQ."qId" = 'e04c848c-9cf5-4de5-8d2b-b10d12a16505' 
          AND (
            FQ."oIds" @> ARRAY[ '68f44665-0200-44dc-94d1-b43a4752b854' ] :: UUID[]
          )
    );
```

But the above query gives 0 rows instead.

On running the above queries individually :-

Subquery 1 :- Gives 8 rows

```sql
Select * from "FormResponseQuestions" as FQ where (
          FQ."qId" = 'a04c848c-9cf5-4de5-8d2b-b10d12a16501' 
          AND (
            FQ."oIds" @> ARRAY[ '1385b9cd-662d-43e0-8dbb-1bbc3977c7bb' ] :: UUID[]
          )
      )
```

Subquery 2 :- Gives 55 rows

```sql
Select * from "FormResponseQuestions" as FQ where (
          FQ."qId" = 'e04c848c-9cf5-4de5-8d2b-b10d12a16505' 
          AND (
            FQ."oIds" @> ARRAY[ '68f44665-0200-44dc-94d1-b43a4752b854' ] :: UUID[]
          )
    );
```

**WHAT I WANT TO DO IS :- Take the result (FormResponseQuestions) from `Subquery 1` and find it `parent (rows from Response table)` then take the result form `Subquery 2` (FormResponseQuestions) and find it's `parent (rows from Response table)`. Then find the common rows among both `Response` & return them**

`@>` means `contains (which checks if oIds contains the id in the ARRAY)` bcz I am using Postgres database with column type Array.

What I am actually trying to do it filter question by responses. As you can see in below image

https://ibb.co/JCvMgXF

The original query looks like this

```sql
SELECT 
  "FormResponse".*, 
  "questions"."id" AS "questions.id", 
  "questions"."rId" AS "questions.rId", 
  "questions"."qId" AS "questions.qId", 
  "questions"."oIds" AS "questions.oIds", 
  "questions"."shortAnswer" AS "questions.shortAnswer", 
  "questions"."longAnswer" AS "questions.longAnswer", 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      "FormResponse"."id", 
      "FormResponse"."formId", 
      "FormResponse"."responderId", 
      "FormResponse"."responseLabels", 
      "FormResponse"."createdAt", 
      "FormResponse"."updatedAt" 
    FROM 
      "FormResponses" AS "FormResponse" 
    WHERE 
      "FormResponse"."formId" = 'a04c848c-9cf5-4de5-8d2b-b10d12a16547' 
      AND (
        SELECT 
          "rId" 
        FROM 
          "FormResponseQuestions" AS "questions" 
        WHERE 
          (
            (
              (
                "questions"."qId" = 'a04c848c-9cf5-4de5-8d2b-b10d12a16501' 
                AND (
                  "questions"."oIds" @ > ARRAY[ '1385b9cd-662d-43e0-8dbb-1bbc3977c7bb' ] :: UUID[]
                )
              ) 
              AND (
                "questions"."qId" = 'c04c848c-9cf5-4de5-8d2b-b10d12a16503' 
                AND (
                  "questions"."oIds" @ > ARRAY[ '2c47f7cf-0ff8-4741-a260-5f5bc2b39a43' ] :: UUID[]
                )
              )
            ) 
            AND "questions"."rId" = "FormResponse"."id"
          ) 
        LIMIT 
          1
      ) IS NOT NULL 
    ORDER BY 
      "FormResponse"."createdAt" DESC 
    LIMIT 
      100 OFFSET 0
  ) AS "FormResponse" 
  INNER JOIN "FormResponseQuestions" AS "questions" ON "FormResponse"."id" = "questions"."rId" 
  AND (
    (
      "questions"."qId" = 'a04c848c-9cf5-4de5-8d2b-b10d12a16501' 
      AND (
        "questions"."oIds" @ > ARRAY[ '1385b9cd-662d-43e0-8dbb-1bbc3977c7bb' ] :: UUID[]
      )
    ) 
    AND (
      "questions"."qId" = 'c04c848c-9cf5-4de5-8d2b-b10d12a16503' 
      AND (
        "questions"."oIds" @ > ARRAY[ '2c47f7cf-0ff8-4741-a260-5f5bc2b39a43' ] :: UUID[]
      )
    )
  ) 
ORDER BY 
  "FormResponse"."createdAt" DESC;
```

I have tried using other operators like `OR`, `IN` but the results are not what I am expecting

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: `FQ."qId"` cannot be equal to both `'a04c848c-9cf5-4de5-8d2b-b10d12a16501'` and `'e04c848c-9cf5-4de5-8d2b-b10d12a16505'` in the same row, so connecting the conditions with `AND` will never evaluate to `TRUE`; thus, the query will always return 0 rows.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad. What is the solution for it besides using JOINS?

Comment: you may be looking for `INTERSECT` clause. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-intersect-clause.htm

Comment: I don't know what `parent (rows from Response table)` means.  Does that describe some part of your existing query?

Comment: @jjanes yes I'm referring to the `FormResponse` table as you can see in the original query.